# Converting an array of objects to a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've searched stack overflow quite a lot but cannot get the information needed, hence the question.

As jsonapi expects all the information to be in the form of objects.

I want to convert :

```
[{"id":2,"quantity":2},{"id":1,"quantity":2}]
```

to

```
{"0" : {"id":2,"quantity":2}, "1" : {"id":1,"quantity":2}}
```

**Solution:**
If anyone needs help and doesn't want to get down voted for merely asking a question out of confusion.

```
function toObject(arr) {
      var obj = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] !== undefined) obj[i] = arr[i];
      return obj;
    }
```

Comment: There are no "objects of objects" in JavaScript. Fix the API to accept proper JSON.

Comment: There is no such thing in JS. That's not possible.

Comment: Your `object of objects` should be with keys and values like: `{"k2": {"id":2,"quantity":2}, "k1":{"id":1,"quantity":2}}`

Comment: @avrahamcool Thought as much, Yes that's what I want. let me paste my entire deal object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you desire isn't valid. All JSON objects work by key,value pair hence this wouldn't work :

```
{
    {"id":2,"quantity":2},
    {"id":1,"quantity":2}
}
```

Because you don't have any keys in the root object. You could do this though :

```
{
    "key1": {"id":2,"quantity":2},
    "key2": {"id":1,"quantity":2}
}
```

Does the difference seem clear to you ?

Comment: Hello John, that's exactly what I'm looking for, I've updated my question, if you can have a look! : ]